# Notifiying the user a method did not suceed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method, which returns void. It sets some values in an array, depending on an if/else statement.

However, if the code enters the else statement, this operation cannot be performed. What could I return to the calling method (a method in the code-behind of a winforms form), to indicate this operation did not suceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use as OUT parameter, Out parameter must be assigned within the method, before it return the value or else compiler will raise the error.

```
void SomeFunction (someparameter of yor req, out bool result)
{
   if(success) // if everty things go well, you assign out variable 
   {
     result=true;
   }
   else
   {
     result=false; 
   }
}
```

[Out Parameter Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You could change the `void` to `int`, `bool` or a `result` enumeration of some sort. The caller can then retrieve this value and check if the call was successful. For example, `true` is returned if the operation succeeded and `false` is returned if it didn't. If the method has to remain a `void`, you could use an `out` parameter which the caller then reads to check whether or not the call was successful. Alternatively, you could throw an exception and have the caller handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Have your method return a bool indicating success/failure.

Comment: Thanks. I did think of that ,was wondering if there was a way to do this without changing the return type! But I guess not?

Comment: @dotnetdev - You can use an `out` parameter if you don't want to change the return type.